# bitbucket, cannot pull an update, resulting an 403 error

Tags: git, bitbucket

hellp, I use command: `git pull` and get the following error:

```
[remote: To make a call, you need to use an app password.
fatal: unable to access 'https://my-username@bitbucket.org/blablabla/blabalblabla.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I have 4 people in a team.

Comment: 403 is a forbidden error, so you're potentially not logged in.

Comment: In what particular branch are you pulling your code? Do you have any access to that repo?

Comment: it doesn't ask me to login. not prompting the password. I can successfully login via browser...

Comment: I am owner of the repo. i have access 100%. i have two-factor authentication system enabled. but it does not promt me for anything

Comment: yes, I have turned off 2FA and now it pulls ok. strange thing. how to solve this, with enabled 2FA ? git version 2.17.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try cloning with SSH, rather than HTTPS. With HTTPS, you'll need to login and also use your 2FA. With SSH, you can bypass this check when you pull, but leave 2FA turned on for logins via browser. There is a guide to setting up SSH here https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use an app password, which is a scoped alternate password meant for use in configuration scripts but which cannot be used to log onto the UI. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html

Comment: How to you provide the app password to the `git pull` command line?

Answer (score 0):

Mine occurred when the user access to the repository was limited to either read/write. Make access to it as admin.